# HQL and Session.Query ignores eager fetching defined in mapping

Tags: linq, nhibernate, hql, eager-loading, queryover

I have a problem with NHibernate not using my mappings configuration for eager loading a collection when I get something using HQL or Linq (Session.Query). Session.Get and Session.QueryOver is working like expected.

I'm using NHibernate 3.2. Here's the mapping of a collection in my Product mapping.

```
<bag name="OrderItems" inverse="true" cascade="none" lazy="false" fetch="join">
  <key column="order_id" />
  <one-to-many class="OrderItem" />
</bag>
```

and from the other side the mapping looks like this:

```
<many-to-one name="Product" class="Product" column="product_id" not-null="true" />
```

I have 4 Tests, 2 are successfull and 2 are not. They use Session.SessionFactory.Statistics to keep track of CollectionFetchCount (was OrderItems selected in 1 joined query or in a separate). The intent is to have OrderItems selected and loaded when selecting the product as OrderItems are almost always accessed as well.

LastCreated is a simple reference to the last product inserted into the DB.

```cs
[Test] /* Success */
public void Accessing_Collection_Using_Session_Get_Results_In_1_Select()
{

    // Get by Id
    var product = Session.Get<Product>(LastCreated.Id);
    var count = product.OrderItems.Count;
    Assert.AreEqual(0,statistics.CollectionFetchCount,"Product collectionfetchcount using Get");
}


[Test] /* Success */
public void Accessing_Collection_Using_Session_QueryOver_Results_In_1_Select()
{

    // Get by Id
    var product = Session.QueryOver<Product>().SingleOrDefault();
    var count = product.OrderItems.Count;
    Assert.AreEqual(0, statistics.CollectionFetchCount, "Product collectionfetchcount using QueryOver");
}
```

```cs
[Test] /* Fail */
public void Accessing_Collection_Using_Session_Query_Results_In_1_Select()
{

    // Get by IQueryable and Linq
    var product = Session.Query<Product>().Single(x => x.Id == LastCreated.Id);

    var count = product.OrderItems.Count;
    Assert.AreEqual(0, statistics.CollectionFetchCount, "Product collectionfetchcount using Linq");
}

[Test] /* Fail */
public void Accessing_Collection_Using_HQL_Results_In_1_Select()
{

    // Get by IQueryable and Linq
    var product = Session.CreateQuery("from Product where Id = :id")
        .SetParameter("id",LastCreated.Id)
        .UniqueResult<Product>();

    var count = product.OrderItems.Count;
    Assert.AreEqual(0, statistics.CollectionFetchCount, "Product collectionfetchcount using HQL");
}
```

Is this intended behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HQL queries will not respect a `fetch="join"` set in mapping. This is because they are freeform queries, making it impossible for NH to guess how to transform them to add the join.

Linq is implemented as a wrapper for HQL, QueryOver is a wrapper for Criteria; that's why you see the different behaviors.

If you need eager loads in Linq/HQL, you will have to make them explicit in the query (using `join fetch` and `Fetch()/FetchMany()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm a bit confused though as the NHibernate reference for HQL from nhforge says: "In addition, a "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be initialized along with their parent objects, using a single select. This is particularly useful in the case of a collection. It effectively overrides the outer join and lazy declarations of the mapping file for associations and collections." Which to me implies that it should look at the mapping file. Or what behaviour are the docs talking about overriding?

Comment: If the mapping does not declare any eager fetching, you're overriding it with the `join fetch`... The doc wording is a bit misleading here.